# swiftUI - tabBar & navigationBar in the same view

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, tabbar

**HOW DO I MAKE THEM BOTH APPEAR IN THE VIEW?**

I'm trying to make a view with both tabbar & navigationbar,

but it's either shows the navigationBar or the tabBar (depends on which I put first \ on top)

for example - this will show only the Navigation Bar:

```
var body: some View {
        
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        
        NavigationView{
        
            CustomTableView(lang: $lang)
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Home")
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }

            
        //NavigationBar Title:
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        let title = "Title"
                        Text(title)
                                .font(.title)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image(Constants.logoImage).resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of them are placed at the same position. What do you expect from this? One item on top of another at the same position?

Where do you want to show for these both?

Comment: Put the tab item part on the NavigationView. Each tab can have its own. You shouldn’t put the navigation view above the tan view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabView` interpret `NavigationView` as just a first page view w/o tab item, so nothing is shown. Here is possible fix:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    
    NavigationView {
    
        CustomTableView(lang: $lang)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    let title = "Title"
                    Text(title)
                            .font(.title)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Image(Constants.logoImage).resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                }
    }
    .tag(0)        // << place here !!
    .tabItem {
        Text("Home")
        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
    }
}
```